# Values and captions in Ace Editor autocomplete

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, ace-editor

I am using Ace Editor v.1.1.8 with ext-language_tools.
I want to achieve the following behavior with auto-complete:

User starts typing, presses Ctrl+Space and I show him the list of found captions, when he selects one of them the value is inserted.

My code:

```
var completions = [
    {id: 'id1', 'value': 'value1'}, 
    {id: 'id2', 'value': 'value2'}
];
var autoCompleter = {
    getCompletions: function(editor, session, pos, prefix, callback) {
        if (prefix.length === 0) {
            callback(null, []);
            return;
        }                    
        callback(
            null,
            completions.map(function(c) {
                    return {value: c.id, caption: c.value};
                })
        );
    }
};
editor.setOptions({
    enableBasicAutocompletion: [autoCompleter],
    enableLiveAutocompletion: false,
    enableSnippets: false
});
```

So what I need from the above is that user enters 'val', sees the list with 'value1' and 'value2', selects one of them and 'id1' or 'id2' is inserted into editor.

At this point:

- Editor always searches by value (and i need to search by caption)
- If I set 'value' = c.value, then editor will search correctly but will insert c.value while I need c.id inserted.

Here's the working code: http://plnkr.co/edit/8zAZaLpZVhocHmI4GWhd?p=preview

UPD:

Was able to achieve this behavior by adding insertMatch method to data:

```
completions.map(function(c) {
    return {
        value: c.name,            
        meta: c.id,
        completer: {
            insertMatch: function(editor, data) {
                if (editor.completer.completions.filterText) {
                    var ranges = editor.selection.getAllRanges();
                    for (var i = 0, range; range = ranges[i]; i++) {
                        range.start.column -= editor.completer.completions.filterText.length;
                        editor.session.remove(range);
                    }
                }
                editor.execCommand("insertstring", data.meta);
            }
        }
    };
})
```

Comment: creating separate completer object for each completion is a bad idea, put insertmatch on autoCompleter and use `completer: autoCompleter`

Comment: I tried that, but it won't work - https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.1.8/lib/ace/autocomplete.js#L180

Comment: what exactly didn't work? i meant something like  http://plnkr.co/edit/g3Z2opgXRGhp89tK3as5?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change

```
var caption = item.value || item.caption || item.snippet;
```

line at https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.1.8/lib/ace/autocomplete.js#L449 to

```
var caption = item.caption || item.value || item.snippet;
```

You can also implement custom insertMatch method on completer https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.1.8/lib/ace/autocomplete.js#L181, but making a pull request with first option is better

Comment: I am against the first option as you have to meddle with library code making it impossible to update it in future etc.
I am able to achieve what I need by creating insertMatch method.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You don't have to meddle with library code, Ace is open source so you can create a pull request to Ace with the fix.